# Updating/Adding value to array in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, database

I am new developer, and I seem to be stuck on handling arrays in laravel. I am using Laravel 8, and I cant seem to solve this situation.

I am building an internal recruitment site, where once a manager posts a job, employees will be able to apply to those specific jobs. I have defined the table in the database to have the "applicants" as an array consisting of the user_id's. However, I seem to not be able to add more than one array to it.

Below is my Recruitment Model

```
class Recruitment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'salary',
        'term_start',
        'term_end',
        'deadline',
        'details',
        'status',
        'applicants',
    ];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo("\App\Models\User");
    }

    protected $casts = [
        'applicants' => 'array'
    ];
}
```

Next is my migration (I am using text format, because the DB on the server is older and does not support json)

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('recruitments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->decimal('salary', 10, 2);
            $table->date('term_start');
            $table->date('term_end');
            $table->date('deadline');
            $table->longText('details');
            $table->string('status');
            $table->text('applicants')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Here is my blade

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card col-sm-12 py-3">
            <div class="card-header border d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <h3 class="w-75">{{ $job->title }}</h3>
                <div class="w-25">
                    <p class="my-0 my-0">Created at: <span class="text-info">{{ $job->created_at }}</span></p>
                    <p class="my-0 my-0">Last updated at: <span class="text-primary">{{ $job->updated_at }}</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                // display job details here

                <form action="{{ route('add-applicant', ['id' => $job->id ]) }}" method="POST" class="col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    @csrf
                    <input type="text" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" hidden>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success w-25">Apply</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and lastly my controller

```
public function addApplicant($id, Request $reqst){
        $job = Recruitment::find($id);
        $user[] = $reqst->user_id;

        $job->applicants = $user;
        $job->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

While this controller will be able to save an array, it unfortunately overwrites the already existing one (let's say a second user applied). When I try to use an array_push, it does nothing, and I still end up with just one value in the array.

Sorry this was a bit of a read, but I appreciate any help I cen get with this. Thanks

Comment: Don't store arrays. Better set up a model and relation for your applicants

Comment: This $job->applicants = $user; - should be $job->applicants =  $job->applicants.",".$user; . This will append the new applicant id with a coma in front.  There may be duplicate ids here that you may have to check.

Answer (score 0):

Try in

```
public function addApplicant($id, Request $reqst){
        $job = Recruitment::find($id);

        $job->applicants = $reqst->user_id;
        $job->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

and in Recruitment model should have

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'applicants');
    }
```

and migration file

```
$table->integer('applicants')->nullable();
```